# How to "protect" a folder from Windows Media Player (preventing it from messing up album covers)

Tags: windows-10, acl

In addition to [Windows Media Player 12 shows wrong cover art when playing](https://superuser.com/questions/325488/windows-media-player-12-shows-wrong-cover-art-when-playing?rq=1) I would like to try option 1 from the accepted answer, but I don't know how to protect a folder, i.e. deny rights with ACL. Can anyone provide me step-by-step instructions how to do so in Windows 10?

> "Protect" the folder containing the MP3 by creating empty Folder.jpg and AlbumArtSmall.jpg, and then denying write on them with ACL.

Comment: The post you quoted also links to [here](https://lionsphil.livejournal.com/57126.html).

Comment: Thanks, however, I still struggle with setting the ACL for "Everybody". I don't see this option, I see "Authenticated Users", "SYSTEM", "Admin" and "User". Also, I don't see the mentioned "read only" box. I just see "Full access", etc.

Comment: I reformulated my question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1649104/how-to-exactly-protect-a-folder-from-windows-media-player-preventing-it-from?noredirect=1#comment2522276_1649104