# How to exactly “protect” a folder from Windows Media Player (preventing it from messing up album covers)

Tags: windows-10, acl

I struggle with the following two instructions mentioned on on [this blog post](https://lionsphil.livejournal.com/57126.html) for [Windows Media Player 12 shows wrong cover art when playing](https://superuser.com/questions/325488/windows-media-player-12-shows-wrong-cover-art-when-playing?rq=1)

> Then (separately, else you won't get the Security tab) bring up each one's properties in Explorer, and drill down to the access control list for Everybody (you might need to add one).

Well, I don't see "Everybody", how can I add this "Everybody" option?

> Now in the ACL windows, tick to Deny Write for these files

Which options do I have to tick exactly? There are quite many options available (Full access, Change, Read, Run, ...)

Comment: Does MediaPlayer really modifies the files or does it simply shows the wrong cover?

Comment: It actually DOES modify and create new hidden files, I checked - it's hilarious that this huge bug never got fixed in the first place...

Comment: Windows Media Player is ancient and outdated software that's not developed any more. You would do better to uninstall it and use better software such as [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/). See [link](https://millennialdiyer.com/diys/music/wmp-album-cover-art-fix-with-mediamonkey/).

Comment: VLC looks ugly, even with skins, that's why WMP is still my first choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see the `Everybody` user, you will need to add it yourself: click `Add` and then type `Everybody` in the text field. Note that if you're running a non-English version of Windows, you will need to actually enter the translation of `Everybody` to the language of your system. Next, click `Check Names`. If the text that you entered becomes underlined then that means that it was recognized and you can click `OK`.

As for which options to tick, simply ticking the `Write` option under the `Deny` heading should do the trick. You can verify your changes by opening the file in WordPad (not Notepad), entering some text and trying to save. Saving should fail with an access denied error.

Comment: The German word for the `Everybody` Group is `Jeder`